# Send MTOM encoded SOAP request to C# webservice using Node.js

Tags: c#, node.js, web-services, wcf, soap

I need to send a SOAP request using Node.js to a web-service built using C#. The service requires us to encrypt an XML using AES algorithm, and then sending the data to a given endpoint as bytes (encoded using MTOM).
I have successfully encrypted the data and verified its correctness.
Now, I am not sure about how to wrap the data in SOAP headers/tags and sending MTOM encoded bytes using Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

There are a handful of projects that can help you out.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws.js

and

https://www.npmjs.com/package/wcf.js

Both do MTOM